# Rails, Sphinx and SQL injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-injection, sphinx

Looking for how to make my sphinx search terms secure, I came across this post:

> http://www.kpdirection.com/featured/how-to-avoid-thinking-sphinx-injection-attacks/#comment-42556

However, It is somewhat old. I couldn't find nothing in Sphinx documentation of how to prevent SQL injections. What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umm, The obvious thing to point out is sphinx is not a SQL database. It will not execute arbitary 'sql' commands.

There is sphinxQL - which is a way to communicate with mysql like SQL syntax. But 1) thinking-sphinx doesnt use it and 2) standard sql-injection precautions work there (eg using prepared queries)

Comment: Even if you could inject some malicious'SQL' into a SphinxQL statement, the worst that could happen is that you would lose some records from your index. Since most installations of Sphinx re-index all data regularly, this shouldn't be that terrible of an issue.

Comment: @ChrisHenry Think of a shop and no listing anymore in the results, and you got the wolf in your house!! %)P